# VaadinOnKotlin.dataSource undefined

Tags: vaadin

I'm new to web development and started experimenting with VaadinOnKotlin. In Bootstrap.kt I have  this code

```
val cfg = HikariConfig().apply {
    jdbcUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test_db"
    username = "joe"
    password = "public"
}
cfg.driverClassName = org.postgresql.Driver::class.java.getName()
JdbiOrm.setDataSource(HikariDataSource(cfg))

VaadinOnKotlin.init()

val flyway = Flyway.configure()
        .dataSource(VaadinOnKotlin.dataSource)
        .load()
flyway.migrate()
```

VaadinOnKotlin.dataSource or VaadinOnKotlin.getDataSource() are undefined.

They get defined if I import eu.vaadinonkotlin.sql2o.dataSource, but doing that causes following crash

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void com.github.vokorm.VokOrm.init()'
        at eu.vaadinonkotlin.sql2o.VokOrmPlugin.init(VokOrmPlugin.kt:12) ~[na:na]
        at eu.vaadinonkotlin.VaadinOnKotlin.init(VaadinOnKotlin.kt:17) ~[na:na]
        at com.smartiops.epsilon.Bootstrap.contextInitialized(Bootstrap.kt:59) ~[na:na]
```

Could this be a version issue? I see this in my build.gradle.kts

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.72"
    id("org.gretty") version "3.0.3"
    war
    id("com.vaadin") version "0.8.0"
}
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. In build.gradle.kts I had to add

```
dependencies {
    implementation("eu.vaadinonkotlin:vok-framework-vokdb:0.8.2")
}
```

and in Bootstrap.kts I had to add

```
import eu.vaadinonkotlin.vokdb.dataSource
```